# Which version of LSTMs are implemented in Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, theano, lstm

Which exact LSTM (Long-Short-Term-Memory) neural network model does the [Keras](https://keras.io/) Python library implement? Is it the "basic" version outlined [here](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/), or if it is a variation such as [Gers & Schmidhuber](ftp://ftp.idsia.ch/pub/juergen/TimeCount-IJCNN2000.pdf), which one is it? In particular, I need to know the exact internal connections as well as their respective activation functions.

I would like to know this because I am training a model using Keras which I would like to use for prediction on a device on which Python is not available - therefore I need to implement my own LSTM (and use the weights from the trained Keras model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like they are using [Hochreiter 1997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/13853244_Long_Short-term_Memory) - at least [it says so in a comment in the code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py).

Answer (score 1):

If you check the comments in the code you will see that forget gates are implemented an aspect that is not mention on Hochreiter 1997 work. According to tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/rnn_cell/LSTMCell) they use the version presented by [Gers et al., 1999](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/818041) where forget gates where presented.